# PHP fopen() not working. file exists, path is correct, permission checked

Tags: php, fopen

I'm trying to open a file with fopen() but it doesn't work.

"Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty"

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$file = 'output/example.csv';    
$handle = fopen("$file", "r");
if ($handle != FALSE) {
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

I checked if the file exists and if the path is correct.

```
echo $file;
```

gives me "output/example.csv"

I can't figure it out. In an other php script the code above works fine...

Need help please. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

*********EDIT*********
Maybe I should precise my problem and post a bigger part of my code:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
clearstatcache();
require('mainConfig.php');

################ Save & delete markers #################
if($_POST) //run only if there's a post data
{
    //make sure request is comming from Ajax
    $xhr = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'; 
    if (!$xhr){ 
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Request must come from Ajax!'); 
        exit(); 
    }

     /***** Datei öffnen *****/
    $code = filter_var($_POST["mfileName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $file = 'output/'.$code.".csv";
    echo "file to open: ".$file."<br>";
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        echo "file doesn't exist: ".$file."<br>";
    } else {
        echo "file exists: ".$file."<br>";
    }

    $directory = 'output/backup/versions/'.$code;
    if (!file_exists($directory)) {
        mkdir($directory, 777, true);
    }
    $handle = fopen($file, "rb"); // 'r' = Lese und Schreib Rechte

    if (!$handle) {
        echo "Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Datei konnte nicht geöffnet werden.<br>";
    }
    fclose($handle);

    $i = 0; 
    if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
            if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
                $i++;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    $versionFileNameAndPath = 'output/backup/versions/'.$code.'/'.$code.'_versionNr_'.$i.".csv";
    echo "copy Ziel-Datei: ".$versionFileNameAndPath."<br>";
    if (!file_exists($versionFileNameAndPath)) {
        if ( copy($file , $versionFileNameAndPath) ) {
          // file copied.
        } else {
            print_r(error_get_last());
          // error occurred..call error_get_last() function for err details.      
        }
    }
    $handle = fopen($file, "r"); // 'r' = Lese und Schreib Rechte
    $managedPinArray = "";
    $managedPinArrayIndexInFile = 0;
    if ($handle != FALSE) {
        echo "Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Datei konnte geöffnet werden.";
    } else {
        $connection = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
...
etc.
```

And this gives me the following Output:

```
file to open: output/69-1407031331-de.csv
file exists: output/69-1407031331-de.csv
copy Ziel-Datei: output/backup/versions/69-1407031331-de/69-1407031331-de_versionNr_0.csv

Warning: copy(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\guide\map_process.php on line 49
Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => copy(): Filename cannot be empty [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\guide\map_process.php [line] => 49 )
Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\guide\map_process.php on line 56
```

Comment: Replace `$handle = fopen("$file", "r");` with `$handle = fopen($file, "r");`

Comment: doesn't work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
$file = 'output/'.$code.".csv";
// ... other code ...
while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
// ... other code ...
copy($file , $versionFileNameAndPath)
```

You're reusing the `$file` variable and at the end of your `while` loop it will be `false` (hence, the notice about an empty file name).

Answer (score 1):

You got error in if

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$file = 'output/example.csv';    
$handle = fopen("$file", "r");
if (!$handle) {
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

try this code, your condition was "if $handle is not false report error"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the entire address where is the file

Ex 
In windows

**c:\\some\\output\\example.csv**

In linux

**/home/some/example.csv**